# find the missing braces in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written the logic to check for parenthesis for "(" and ")" but there seems to an issue when parenthesis gets mixed. This is because I'm just comparing the total parenthesis count.

**This is what i wrote**

```js
function checkParanthesis(str){
  var depth=0;
  for(var i in str){
    if(str[i] == "(" || str[i] == "{" || str[i] == "[")
      depth++;
    else if(str[i] == ")" || str[i] == "}" || str[i] == "]")
      depth--;
  }
  
  if(depth !==0) return false;
  
  return true;
}

console.log(checkParanthesis("() test"));
```

**Question:**

> But how can I check for multiple parenthesis elements? (){}[]

For example,

**Input:**

```
"[(]) abcd" // should return false
"[{()}] test" // should return true
```

Should return false (Not true)

Comment: the last statement is redundant, a simple check if the value is `!== 0` would be adequate.

Comment: Corrected! thank you @RyanMcCullagh

Comment: You have to keep track of the opening braces so you can make sure a closing one corresponds with the most recent still-open one.

Comment: Instead of just counting braces, you may want to use a stack. Push left parentheses to the stack, when you encounter right parentheses you pop off the stack and compare.

Comment: Even without mixing parentheses, you'll run into trouble with `)(`.  I think Ryan meant that the last bit should be `return depth===0`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an array as a stack to keep track of unresolved opening braces:

```
function checkParanthesis(str){
  var stack=[];
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == "(" || str[i] == "{" || str[i] == "[")
      stack.push(str[i]);
    else if(str[i] == ")") {
        if(stack.pop() != "(") { return false; }
    }
    else if(str[i] == "}") {
        if(stack.pop() != "{") { return false; }
    }
    else if(str[i] == "]") {
        if(stack.pop() != "[") { return false; }
    } 
  }

  return !stack.length;
}
```

You can probably clean this up to be more readable, but basically:

- Every time you find an opening brace, add it to the stack.
- Every time you see a closing brace, pop the stack and see if the stack's top is a matching opening brace.

  - If it's not, you have a mismatch, so you can immediately return `false`.
- If you make it to the end, you didn't spot any errors, return `true` if the stack is empty (i.e., `stack.length` is `0`).

(Note I also changed your `i in str` loop since it will iterate over properties on `String.prototype`.)

One cleanup you could do (but I'm not sure if this makes the code more readable or not) would be to put the brace pairings in an object, with the closing character as the key and the corresponding opening character as the value. Then, see if the current character exists as a key `in` the object, and if so, pop the stack and see if the value for that key matches:

```
function checkParanthesis(str){
  var stack=[];
  var brace_pairings = { ")":"(", "}":"{", "]":"[" };
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == "(" || str[i] == "{" || str[i] == "[") {
      stack.push(str[i]);
    } else if(str[i] in brace_pairings) {
        if(stack.pop() != brace_pairings[str[i]]) { return false; }
    }
  }

  return !stack.length;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than a counter, you could use a stack, pushing a token onto the stack when an opening bracket is seen, and popping from the stack when *the correct* closing bracket is seen. If a closing bracket is encountered when a different type of bracket is at the top of the stack, or when the stack is empty, the string is unbalances.

Something like this (not polished and tested):

```
function checkParanthesis(str){
var stack = [];
var open;
for(var i in str){
  if(str[i] == "(" || str[i] == "{" || str[i] == "[") {
    stack.push(str[i]);
  }
  else if(str[i] == ")" || str[i] == "}" || str[i] == "]") {
    if ( stack.length == 0 ) {
       return false;
    }
    open = stack.pop();
    if (
       ( open == '(' && str[i] != ')' )
       || ( open == '[' && str[i] != ']' )
       || ( open == '{' && str[i] != '}' )
     ) {
       return false;
    }
  }
}

 if ( stack.length > 0 ) {
   return false;
 }

 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to get all the braces in a `match()` array...then remove each end of array testing each set

```js
function checkParanthesis(str) {
  //hashmap to compare open/close braces
  var closers = {'[': ']','(': ')','{': '}'};
  // create braces array
  var parStack = str.match(/\(|\{|\[|\)|\}|\]/g) || [];

  if (parStack.length % 2 !== 0) {//must have even number
    return false;
  } else {
    while (parStack.length) {
      // check each end of array against each other.
      if (closers[parStack.shift()] !== parStack.pop()) {
        //mismatch , we're done
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

}
console.log('no braces ', checkParanthesis("test"));
console.log('matched ', checkParanthesis("() test"));
console.log('mis matched ',checkParanthesis("[(]) abcd")); // should return false
console.log('matched ',checkParanthesis("[{()}] test"));
```

Comment: @Teepeemm actually I don't think it would

Answer (score 0):

The array/stack/counter approach reads the string from left to right.  Another approach is to work from the inside out.

```
function checkParanthesis(str){
  while ( str.indexOf('()')>=0 || str.indexOf('[]')>=0 || str.indexOf('{}')>=0 ) {
    str = str.replace('()','').replace('[]','').replace('{}','');
  }
  return str.length===0;
}
```

You could use regular expressions for the replace part to do a global replace and loop fewer times.  The downside is that you'd need to escape everything in sight: `str.replace(/\(\)/g,'')` et.c.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was working on leetCode and find your question, I found this article was written pretty clear about the problem and I tested it and I quoted here:

Click [here](https://paulrohan.medium.com/parenthesis-matching-problem-in-javascript-the-hacking-school-hyd-7d7708278911)!
Parenthesis Matching Problem in JavaScript

```
let isMatchingBrackets = function (str) {
    let stack = [];
    let map = {
        '(': ')',
        '[': ']',
        '{': '}'
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // If character is an opening brace add it to a stack
        if (str[i] === '(' || str[i] === '{' || str[i] === '[' ) {
            stack.push(str[i]);
        }
        //  If that character is a closing brace, pop from the stack, which will also reduce the length of the stack each time a closing bracket is encountered.
        else {
            let last = stack.pop();

            //If the popped element from the stack, which is the last opening brace doesn’t match the corresponding closing brace in the map, then return false
            if (str[i] !== map[last]) {return false};
        }
    }
    // By the completion of the for loop after checking all the brackets of the str, at the end, if the stack is not empty then fail
        if (stack.length !== 0) {return false};

    return true;
}
```