# String comparison special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

The input string for the following function is: `"()[]{}"`

```
var isValid = function(s) {
  if ((s.length == 2 && s[0] == s[1]) || s.trim().length == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (s.length % 2 != 0) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = s.length / 2, j = i - 1; i < s.length && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
    console.log(s[j], s[i])
    if (s[i].charCodeAt(0) !== s[j].charCodeAt(0)) {
      console.log("false", s[j].length, s[i].length)
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

when it is comparing [ and ] it enters into if condition inside the for loop and returns false.

I tried comparing  `s[i] != s[j]` still the same problem.

description:

Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

```
Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
```

Note that an empty string is also considered valid.

```
Example 1:

Input: "()"
Output: true

Example 2:

Input: "()[]{}"
Output: true

Example 3:

Input: "(]"
Output: false

Example 4:

Input: "([)]"
Output: false
```

Comment: What is the function `isValid` supposed to do? Please create a [mcve] with the desired behavior

Comment: What's your main objective of this code? What are the conditions to be fulfilled?

Comment: @adiga  edited and added the description of the problem

Comment: @hygull  edited and added the description of the problem

Comment: This reminds me of [a problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/). It's better to solve it with stacks.

Comment: @Hao Wu but why code is not working.

Comment: [find the missing braces in a string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182927)

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex makes the validation much easier.
the validation will check for  **/(()|{}|[])/g** and when **(), {} or []** is found then will remove it from the string until the string is empty.

let's say we have this string **"([]){}{[]}()"**, so what the function will do is keeping removing the **(), {} or []** until remove all the string. if the string was not empty after the loop is finishing that`s mean there is extra **(, { or [**.
the function dosn't see the **(), {} or []** when they are external just keep removing the inner until the the external beeing inner.

```
function validParentheses(parens) {
  while(/(\(\)|\{\}|\[\])/g.test(parens)) parens = parens.replace(/(\(\)|\{\}|\[\])/g, '');
  return parens ? false : true;
}

console.log(validParentheses('(([{}]){}[])()'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Here, I have removed many parts of your written code and made it working.

**Note:**
As JavaScript's object is very fast in case of search so I used to map the related brackets. Code is just straightforward so I haven't added comments.

> You can also check the below running code at https://rextester.com/CJMZ17507.

```
//nodejs v4.2.6
var brackets = {
    "(": ")",
    "[": "]",
    "{": "}"
}

var isValid = function(s) {
    var valid = false
    var index = 0

    if(s.length % 2 !== 0)
        return false

    while(index < s.length -1){
        ch = s[index]
        if(ch in brackets) {
            if(brackets[ch] === s[index + 1]) {
                index += 2
                valid = true
                continue
            } else {
                valid = false
                break
            }
        } else {
            valid = false
            break
        }
    }

    if(valid === false && s.length === 0) {
        valid = true
    }

    return valid;
};

console.log(isValid("[]{}()")) // true
console.log(isValid("[]")) // true
console.log(isValid("")) // true
console.log(isValid("[]{})")) // false
console.log(isValid("[]}{")) // false
console.log(isValid("[]{}(())")) // false
console.log(isValid("([)]")) // false
console.log(isValid("(]")) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simple test cases it is as simple as looping over the array by twos and seeing if the characters match

```js
var oppBracket = {
  '(': ')',
  '{': '}',
  '[': ']'
}

function test(str) {
  // loop over the array by twos
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    // grab the closing bracket that matches the opening bracket
    var opp = oppBracket[str[i]]
    // if we do not have a closing bracket it is false
    // if the next index does not match the closing we found, it fails
    if (!opp || opp !== str[i + 1]) return false
  }
  // if we get here, all the pairs matched
  return true
}

console.log(test("()"))
console.log(test("()[]{}"))
console.log(test("()[]}{"))
```

In real world test cases it could be nested and that method would fail. So it is a simple pop and push

```js
var openBracket = {
  '(': ')',
  '{': '}',
  '[': ']'
}

function test(str) {
  // opens will hold all the brackets that are not matched
  var opens = []
  // Loop over all the characters in the string
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // grab the current character
    var current = str[i]
    // see if it is an opening bracket
    var open = openBracket[current]
    if (open) {
      // if it is push the closing character onto the stack of unclosed brackets
      opens.push(open)
    } else {
      // if it is pop off the last open bracket
      var expecting = opens.pop()
      // see if the current closing bracket matches the last open
      if (current !== expecting) {
        // if it does not the test fails
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  // if we make it here, all the brackets were closed if array is empty
  return opens.length === 0
}

console.log(test("()"))
console.log(test("()[]{}"))
console.log(test("()[]}{"))
console.log(test("(((([]{}))))"))
console.log(test("(((((((((("))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here string input may be empty "" or combination of '(',')','{','}','[',']'.
So, take an empty **array** first. start iterating all characters of input string in a loop, when an **opened character** is coming **push** it to array. Later when any **closed character** coming first check whether this entry's opened character(**for example '[' entry's opened character ']'**) exist or not in array and it must be last entry of the array. If found **pop** it. After checking all iterations if array is  empty return **true** otherwise **false**

```
var isValid = function(s){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        if(s[i] === '(' || s[i] === '{' || s[i] === '[') arr.push(s[i]);
        else{
                if(arr.length === 0) return false;
                switch(s[i]){
                case ')':
                    if(arr[arr.length-1]  === '(') arr.pop();
                    break;
                case '}':
                    if(arr[arr.length-1]  === '{') arr.pop();
                    break;
                case ']':
                    if(arr[arr.length-1]  === '[') arr.pop();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(arr.length === 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @ borchvm Thanks for your feedback. actually I am new here. I think right now solution is more readable.